# Send Response to Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I  show the output of a form  on a browser page and not just on the console ?

Here is my code :

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express()
var http = require('http');

app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    response.send("My Server");
});

app.use(express.static('public'))


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.post('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    let username = req.body.name;
    let password = req.body.password;

    console.log("Just received POST data for users endpoint!");
    console.log(`Data includes: ${username}, ${password}`);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the semicolons

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have configured this route on server-sise:

```
app.post('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    let _username = req.body.name;
    let _password = req.body.password;
    res.send({username: _username, pwd: _password});
});
```

And, client-sie, you are using JQuery and you would making an async request to the server with this HTML form:

```
<form name="module">
    <p>Username</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></p>
    <p>Password</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="password" id="password"></p>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

You can make a POST request and parse the response data in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var _username= $("#username").val();
    var _password= $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<YOUR_NODEJS_SERVER_URL>",
      data: '{"username":_username, "password": _password}',
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response)
      {
        $("#result").html(response.username + "<br/>" + response.pwd);
      },
      error: function(error)
      {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```